# Angular Material virtual scroll not rendering items in unit tests

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I am using `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` + `cdkVirtualFor` in my component and it seems to work fine.

*However in the unit test of that component the items don't get rendered.*

I made a sample app [based on this example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aalxxebvakrd) and while the example works when you serve the app, the test I wrote fails.

### app.module.ts

```
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ScrollingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = Array.from({length: 100000}).map((_, i) => `Item #${i}`);
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{ item }}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

### app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        ScrollingModule,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should render at least 4 items', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelectorAll('.example-item').length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(4); // <-- Error: Expected 0 to be greater than or equal 4.
  });
});
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of your issue to show it. Currently, all we can tell you is "meh, code better and it should go"

Comment: @trichetriche Updated the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Changing the unit test (see in the question) to following resolved it:

```
it('should render at least 4 items', fakeAsync(() => { // <---
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  fixture.autoDetectChanges(); // <--- 
  tick(500); // <---
  const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
  expect(compiled.querySelectorAll('.example-item').length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(4);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks. Saved a lot of time!

Comment: Seems to work! But can you please tell us why this magic happens? Or at least provide a good article from where we can learn? Why there is the need of those 3 statements?

Comment: The virtual scroll doesn't seem to render the items immediately (due to how it's designed inside; see the next answer and links there for more information), so we want to detect the changes automatically and wait a bit until that change happens. And you find plenty of resources on `fakeAsync` and related functions. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Somehow the solution from the previous answer didn't work for my case. Also the alternative solution proposed in [github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14321#issuecomment-479949677) with `flush()` didn't work either.

So my final approach was to check how Google wrote their unit tests for the virtual viewport component. There I noticed that they used a function [`finishInit`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/1565fa3e1e63705efc7f29f98fd1d0f4af66ee93/src/cdk/scrolling/virtual-scroll-viewport.spec.ts#L897) which is a local function in their unit test.

```
/** Finish initializing the virtual scroll component at the beginning of a test. */
function finishInit(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>) {
  // On the first cycle we render and measure the viewport.
  fixture.detectChanges();
  flush();

  // On the second cycle we render the items.
  fixture.detectChanges();
  flush();

  // Flush the initial fake scroll event.
  animationFrameScheduler.flush();
  flush();
  fixture.detectChanges();
}
```

Copied it into my unit test and that seems to work in my case.
It also kinda explains what is happening in the backend.

Comment: This actually works! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Create an async-await test and wait for virtual scroll render finish

```
it('should support cdk virtual scroll', async () => {
    // autoDetectChanges - works fine with virtual scrolling
    fixture.autoDetectChanges();

    // await to virtual scroll render finish
    await fixture.whenStable();
    await fixture.whenRenderingDone();

    // do your expects here
    expect(...foo...).toEqual(...bar...);
});
```

Comment: After trying for days to understand, why my tests fail after switching to virtual-scroll, I found this solution. Works like a charm :-)